# How to get count of certain record saved in Uppercase, lower or a combination using LINQ query

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I need to get the count of `IN / in / In` from `SoccerStatus` regardless if the records are saved in upper case, lower case or a combination of both ie `IN or in or In` from SQLite database in Xamarin Forms. How can I achieve that ?

[image]

```
var count_in = (from x in conn.Table<SoccerAvailability>().Where(x => x.SoccerStatus ==  IN) select x).Count();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string.Equals and tell it to ignore case...

```
var count_in = (from x in conn.Table<SoccerAvailability>().Where(x => string.Equals(x.SoccerStatus, "IN", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) select x).Count();
```

EDIT:  Per your comment I see that the Linq provider you're using doesn't support string.Equals.  You can try the following which should be more portable but possibly a bit slower...

```
var count_in = (from x in conn.Table<SoccerAvailability>().Where(x => x.SoccerStatus.ToUpper() == "IN") select x).Count();
```

Comment: Will try this and reply shortly

Comment: @dazedandconfused- Now I am getting database exception SQLite exception `no such function equals`, could you help me on this